# mysql - multiple rows from two tables and multiple values from one of second table column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
$userid = 1; // got from session
select tableone.userid, tableone.name, tabletwo.action as action
from tableone
leftjoin tabletwo
where tabletwo.userid = $userid
on tableone.jailid = tabletwo.jailid
```

it returns all from tableone and all from tabletwo but the problem is one of the columns of table two i.e. action returns only one however in tabletwo there are more than one rows that matches the condition(tabletwo.userid = $userid on tableone.jailid = tabletwo.jailid).

it returns:

```
userid => 23
name => test title
action => 65

userid => 24
name => test title2
action => 65
```

i want:

```
userid => 23
name => test title
action => [65, 66, 67]

userid => 24
name => test title2
action => [76, 57, 34]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This isn't a valid query in MySQL, so nothing here makes any sense.

Comment: @codepro: I see you've edited your request to fix a typo. You should better have corrected your query. An ON clause belongs with the join (`LEFT JOIN tabletwo ON tableone.jailid = tabletwo.jailid`). Both tables contain a `userid`, but you don't join on it. Is this on purpose? If you outer join `tabletwo` to `tableone`, but then dismiss all results where the `userid` does not match your `$userid`, you end up with an inner join. So do you want an inner join or an outer join really?

Comment: As to your results: Your query returns only two records 23|test title|65 and 24|test title2|65 and no other action codes? And you want action 65 plus other actions for userid 23, but dismiss action 65 for userid 24 and get other actions instead? That makes hardly sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT tableone.userid, tableone.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tabletwo.action) AS action
FROM tableone
LEFT JOIN tabletwo
ON tableone.jailid = tabletwo.jailid
WHERE tabletwo.userid = $userid
GROUP BY tableone.userid, tableone.name;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) the documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Comment: I feel like I'm standing in the Twilight Zone.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @DarshanMehta, it worked, I don't know why but sometimes somebody doesn't understand the issue and downvotes, but I really appreciate you!

Comment: @codepro: No. Your query is syntactically and probably semantically wrong. Darshan builds up on it without even mentioning your flaws. The query in the answer lacks the `ON` clause (which was in the wrong place anyway), so what is called `LEFT JOIN` here is really a `CROSS JOIN` now.

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, it's creepy :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner What is called a LEFT JOIN is actually a syntax error.

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes but MySQL is famous for letting such flaws slip unnoticed. If you omit the ON clause in MySQL you end up with a `CROSS JOIN` without getting warned :-(

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Not in my version.

Comment: @Strawberry: Ah, sorry, you are right. That happens only with inner joins. Outer joins need an `ON` clause even in MySQL.

Comment: I have added `ON` clause btw.

Comment: Yes, but now you've written an INNER JOIN - as EXPLAIN EXTENDED, followed by SHOW WARNINGS would prove.